# Matlab drawing a function within chosen interval

Tags: matlab

I would like to draw this function within a chosen interval:

```
F(d) = ( (1 - e^(-d^(2)) / d )
```

How could I do that?

Comment: simple answer: `d = linspace(start number, end number, number of d); fd = ( (1 - exp(-d.^2) ./ d ); plot(d,fd)`

Comment: So, if i would like 10 points within an interval : [0, 10^-3] The code is  :

`d = linspace(0,0.001, 10); fd = ( (1 - exp(-d.^2) ./ d ))`
` plot(d,fd) ` ?

Comment: yes that's correct. Btw, the parenthesis in the question is not balanced.

Comment: Thx for your help, I got it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [`fplot`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fplot.html) with `fplot(f,xinterval)`:

```
f = @(d) (1 - exp(-d.^(2)) ./ d );
xinterval = [-1 1];
fplot(f,xinterval);
```

[image]

you can use `ezplot` if you have older version of MATLAB.

Comment: use element-wise operators `f = @(d) (1 - exp(-d.^(2)) ./ d );` to avoid unnecessary time spent on matrix operation check

Comment: Indeed. Thanks @Anthony